# PHP fgetcsv() seems can not read the last field of any line from CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I've used `fgetcsv()` function to read data from a CSV file and import its information to MySQL. The data I have is something like this:

```
2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
0,1,2,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,1,7,7,7,7,7,7
```

As you can see, each row has 17 fields and I must read them using their indexes from 0 to 17. But whenever I want to do it, I get an error that tells me there is not any index #17.
What is ther matter with it? I have to add a comma after the last field in each row ? If you answer is yes, why excel does not do it ? And how can I add a new `,` after each line of a CSV file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 17 columns (as you seem to have counted yourself), so you get indices from `0` (first column) to `16` (17th column).